# Is there an equivalence table to convert ASCII smileys to Unicode emoji(s)?

Tags: web, unicode, ascii, emoticons, ascii-art

I would like to find a table to convert the [old school western ascii emoticons](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_emoticons#Western) :-) into their [modern unicode equivalent](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode) ☺.

Do you know if there is one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not everyone agrees on what is what, but here is one such possible table mapping input ASCII-art emoticons to Unicode emoji.  Both data elements are single quoted, so backslashes and single quotes are escaped.

```
'o/'         => '',
'</3'        => '',
'<3'         => '',
'8-D'        => '',
'8D'         => '',
':-D'        => '',
'=-3'        => '',
'=-D'        => '',
'=3'         => '',
'=D'         => '',
'B^D'        => '',
'X-D'        => '',
'XD'         => '',
'x-D'        => '',
'xD'         => '',
':\')'       => '',
':\'-)'      => '',
':-))'       => '',
'8)'         => '',
':)'         => '',
':-)'        => '',
':3'         => '',
':D'         => '',
':]'         => '',
':^)'        => '',
':c)'        => '',
':o)'        => '',
':}'         => '',
':っ)'        => '',
'=)'         => '',
'=]'         => '',
'0:)'        => '',
'0:-)'       => '',
'0:-3'       => '',
'0:3'        => '',
'0;^)'       => '',
'O:-)'       => '',
'3:)'        => '',
'3:-)'       => '',
'}:)'        => '',
'}:-)'       => '',
'*)'         => '',
'*-)'        => '',
':-,'        => '',
';)'         => '',
';-)'        => '',
';-]'        => '',
';D'         => '',
';]'         => '',
';^)'        => '',
':-|'        => '',
':|'         => '',
':('         => '',
':-('        => '',
':-<'        => '',
':-['        => '',
':-c'        => '',
':<'         => '',
':['         => '',
':c'         => '',
':{'         => '',
':っC'        => '',
'%)'         => '',
'%-)'        => '',
':-P'        => '',
':-b'        => '',
':-p'        => '',
':-Þ'        => '',
':-þ'        => '',
':P'         => '',
':b'         => '',
':p'         => '',
':Þ'         => '',
':þ'         => '',
';('         => '',
'=p'         => '',
'X-P'        => '',
'XP'         => '',
'd:'         => '',
'x-p'        => '',
'xp'         => '',
':-||'       => '',
':@'         => '',
':-.'        => '',
':-/'        => '',
':/'         => '',
':L'         => '',
':S'         => '',
':\\'        => '',
'=/'         => '',
'=L'         => '',
'=\\'        => '',
':\'('       => '',
':\'-('      => '',
'^5'         => '',
'^<_<'       => '',
'o/\\o'      => '',
'|-O'        => '',
'|;-)'       => '',
':###..'     => '',
':-###..'    => '',
'D-\':'      => '',
'D8'         => '',
'D:'         => '',
'D:<'        => '',
'D;'         => '',
'D='         => '',
'DX'         => '',
'v.v'        => '',
'8-0'        => '',
':-O'        => '',
':-o'        => '',
':O'         => '',
':o'         => '',
'O-O'        => '',
'O_O'        => '',
'O_o'        => '',
'o-o'        => '',
'o_O'        => '',
'o_o'        => '',
':$'         => '',
'#-)'        => '',
':#'         => '',
':&'         => '',
':-#'        => '',
':-&'        => '',
':-X'        => '',
':X'         => '',
':-J'        => '',
':*'         => '',
':^*'        => '',
'ಠ_ಠ'        => '',
'*\\0/*'     => '',
'\\o/'       => '',
':>'         => '',
'>.<'        => '',
'>:('        => '',
'>:)'        => '',
'>:-)'       => '',
'>:/'        => '',
'>:O'        => '',
'>:P'        => '',
'>:['        => '',
'>:\\'       => '',
'>;)'        => '',
'>_>^'       => '',
```

Comment: @bjb568 ‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪

Comment: Do you have a source for this? By change a list that would get updated?

Comment: Not the above one but similar
https://github.com/wooorm/emoticon/blob/master/index.json

Answer (score 3):

I used Name is carl links to generate this list:

`{
  ,:(: "",
  ,:): "",
  ,:-(: "",
  ,:-): "",
  0:): "",
  0:-): "",
  8-): "",
  :"): "",
  :$: "",
  :'(: "",
  :'): "",
  :'-(: "",
  :'-): "",
  :'-D: "",
  :'D: "",
  :(: "",
  :): "",
  :*: "",
  :,'(: "",
  :,'-(: "",
  :,(: "",
  :,): "",
  :,-(: "",
  :,-): "",
  :,-D: "",
  :,D: "",
  :-"): "",
  :-$: "",
  :-(: "",
  :-): "",
  :-*: "",
  :-/: "",
  :-@: "",
  :-D: "",
  :-o: "",
  :-O: "",
  :-P: "",
  :-S: "",
  :-Z: "",
  :-|: "",
  :/: "",
  :@: "",
  :D: "",
  :o: "",
  :O: "",
  :P: "",
  :s: "",
  :z: "",
  :|: "",
  ;(: "",
  ;): "",
  ;-(: "",
  ;-): "",
  ]:): "",
  ]:-): "",
  B-): "",
  o:): "",
  O:): "",
  O:-): "",
  o:-): "",
  X-): "",
  x-): ""
}`

Answer (score 1):

Found in the code of [markdown-it](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it-emoji/blob/master/lib/data/shortcuts.js) (license MIT)

```
module.exports = {
  mad:              [ '>:(', '>:-(' ], // angry
  blush:            [ ':")', ':-")' ],
  broken_heart:     [ '</3', '<\\3' ],
  // :/ & :\ disabled due conflicts, untill logic improved
  confused:         [ /*':\\',*/ ':-\\', /*':/',*/ ':-/' ], // twemoji shows question
  cry:              [ ":'(", ":'-(", ':,(', ':,-(' ],
  frowning:         [ ':(', ':-(' ],
  heart:            [ '<3' ],
  imp:              [ ']:(', ']:-(' ],
  innocent:         [ 'o:)', 'O:)', 'o:-)', 'O:-)', '0:)', '0:-)' ],
  joy:              [ ":')", ":'-)", ':,)', ':,-)', ":'D", ":'-D", ':,D', ':,-D' ],
  kissing:          [ ':*', ':-*' ],
  laughing:         [ 'x-)', 'X-)' ],
  neutral_face:     [ ':|', ':-|' ],
  open_mouth:       [ ':o', ':-o', ':O', ':-O' ],
  rage:             [ ':@', ':-@' ],
  smile:            [ ':D', ':-D' ],
  smiley:           [ ':)', ':-)' ],
  smiling_imp:      [ ']:)', ']:-)' ],
  sob:              [ ":,'(", ":,'-(", ';(', ';-(' ],
  stuck_out_tongue: [ ':P', ':-P' ],
  sunglasses:       [ '8-)', 'B-)' ],
  sweat:            [ ',:(', ',:-(' ],
  sweat_smile:      [ ',:)', ',:-)' ],
  unamused:         [ ':s', ':-S', ':z', ':-Z', ':$', ':-$' ],
  wink:             [ ';)', ';-)' ]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at
**emoticon**
Info on ASCII emoticons. :p
https://github.com/wooorm/emoticon/blob/master/index.json

[Emot](https://github.com/NeelShah18/emot) is a python library to extract the emojis and emoticons from a text(string).

```
>>> import emot
>>> text = "I love python  :-)"
>>> emot.emoji(text)
>>> [{'value': '', 'mean': ':man:', 'location': [14, 14], 'flag': True}]
>>> emot.emoticons(text)
>>> {'value': [':-)'], 'location': [[16, 19]], 'mean': ['Happy face smiley'], 'flag': True}
```

https://github.com/NeelShah18/emot

Comment: http://asciimoji.com/ seems also relevant for somebody searching for this

Comment: Full Emoji List, v13.0 https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html