# How to convert emoji symbol code ':)' to smiley emoji in PHP

Tags: php

I want to convert the emoji code i.e, ":)" to .

How can I convert it?

Currently I am using p3k detector to detect the emoji's. Below is the code where I can detect the emoji's.

```
  $emoji = \Emoji\detect_emoji($text);
```

Comment: :) is not an emoji

Comment: You've quite a few previously asked questions; any of them solved? It'd be nice and good to know which ones were solved and to mark them off as such.

Answer (score 6):

You need to create your own function to convert (or search online if there is any library that already do this).

```
function stringToEmoji($str) {
    $emojis = [
        'o/'         => '',
        '</3'        => '',
        '<3'         => '',
        '8-D'        => '',
        '8D'         => '',
        ':-D'        => '',
        '=-3'        => '',
        '=-D'        => '',
        '=3'         => '',
        '=D'         => '',
        'B^D'        => '',
        'X-D'        => '',
        'XD'         => '',
        'x-D'        => '',
        'xD'         => '',
        ':\')'       => '',
        ':\'-)'      => '',
        ':-))'       => '',
        '8)'         => '',
        ':)'         => '',
        ':-)'        => '',
        ':3'         => '',
        ':D'         => '',
        ':]'         => '',
        ':^)'        => '',
        ':c)'        => '',
        ':o)'        => '',
        ':}'         => '',
        ':っ)'        => '',
        '=)'         => '',
        '=]'         => '',
        '0:)'        => '',
        '0:-)'       => '',
        '0:-3'       => '',
        '0:3'        => '',
        '0;^)'       => '',
        'O:-)'       => '',
        '3:)'        => '',
        '3:-)'       => '',
        '}:)'        => '',
        '}:-)'       => '',
        '*)'         => '',
        '*-)'        => '',
        ':-,'        => '',
        ';)'         => '',
        ';-)'        => '',
        ';-]'        => '',
        ';D'         => '',
        ';]'         => '',
        ';^)'        => '',
        ':-|'        => '',
        ':|'         => '',
        ':('         => '',
        ':-('        => '',
        ':-<'        => '',
        ':-['        => '',
        ':-c'        => '',
        ':<'         => '',
        ':['         => '',
        ':c'         => '',
        ':{'         => '',
        ':っC'        => '',
        '%)'         => '',
        '%-)'        => '',
        ':-P'        => '',
        ':-b'        => '',
        ':-p'        => '',
        ':-Þ'        => '',
        ':-þ'        => '',
        ':P'         => '',
        ':b'         => '',
        ':p'         => '',
        ':Þ'         => '',
        ':þ'         => '',
        ';('         => '',
        '=p'         => '',
        'X-P'        => '',
        'XP'         => '',
        'd:'         => '',
        'x-p'        => '',
        'xp'         => '',
        ':-||'       => '',
        ':@'         => '',
        ':-.'        => '',
        ':-/'        => '',
        ':/'         => '',
        ':L'         => '',
        ':S'         => '',
        ':\\'        => '',
        '=/'         => '',
        '=L'         => '',
        '=\\'        => '',
        ':\'('       => '',
        ':\'-('      => '',
        '^5'         => '',
        '^<_<'       => '',
        'o/\\o'      => '',
        '|-O'        => '',
        '|;-)'       => '',
        ':###..'     => '',
        ':-###..'    => '',
        'D-\':'      => '',
        'D8'         => '',
        'D:'         => '',
        'D:<'        => '',
        'D;'         => '',
        'D='         => '',
        'DX'         => '',
        'v.v'        => '',
        '8-0'        => '',
        ':-O'        => '',
        ':-o'        => '',
        ':O'         => '',
        ':o'         => '',
        'O-O'        => '',
        'O_O'        => '',
        'O_o'        => '',
        'o-o'        => '',
        'o_O'        => '',
        'o_o'        => '',
        ':$'         => '',
        '#-)'        => '',
        ':#'         => '',
        ':&'         => '',
        ':-#'        => '',
        ':-&'        => '',
        ':-X'        => '',
        ':X'         => '',
        ':-J'        => '',
        ':*'         => '',
        ':^*'        => '',
        'ಠ_ಠ'        => '',
        '*\\0/*'     => '',
        '\\o/'       => '',
        ':>'         => '',
        '>.<'        => '',
        '>:('        => '',
        '>:)'        => '',
        '>:-)'       => '',
        '>:/'        => '',
        '>:O'        => '',
        '>:P'        => '',
        '>:['        => '',
        '>:\\'       => '',
        '>;)'        => '',
        '>_>^'       => '',
        ];

    if(isset($emojis[$str])) {
        return $emojis[$str];
    }

    return null;
}

echo stringToEmoji(':)');
```

Output:

Got list from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581503/1580044

Comment: I don't normally upvote answers that come from another Q&A but given the OP's acceptance record and your finding it, is worth an upvote (from me).

Answer (score 2):

I cannot insert the whole function here because it bypasses stack overflow characters limit. Here's the link to it:

https://gist.github.com/BarryMode/432a7a1f9621e824c8a3a23084a50f60#file-htmlemoji-php

Shortly, the function is

```
preg_replace_callback(pattern, callback, string);
```

Where the **string** is the input where you have emoji that you want to change into html entities. The **pattern** uses regex to find the emoji in the string and then each one is fed into the **callback**, which is where the conversion happens from emoji to html entity.