# How convert emoji as plain text in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, emoji

I have a textarea which naturally in the mobile version gives the possibility of inserting emojis.

```
<textarea data-event="keyup" data-label="text" id="my-field"></textarea>
```

I would like to convert each emoji with plain text as soon as the user inserts an emoji, is there a way with standard string for each unicode emoji ? If that exists, how to do this in javscript or jQuery ?
I found solutions only to remove emojis from the string.

Example of conversion :

to :)

Comment: I found a list here : http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: Do you know that the list of Unicode Emoji is pretty large? They don't have *classic* counterparts.

Comment: I am not aware of the existence of a mapping from Emoji to text, you may have to support only a few and create a mapping yourself.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Yes that was I asked if there is a standard.

Comment: I found thanks the list I added in comments a way to convert emoji to CLDR Short Name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61524478/how-to-convert-unicode-of-an-emoji-into-cldr-short-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could intercept the `paste` event and transform the emoji into its corresponding ASCII text equivalent.

I generated a regular expression from the keys of the lookup map. A space is added before the ASCII text for padding; in the case where simultaneous/adjacent emoji are pasted at once.

```js
const emojiMapper = {
  "": ":)",
  "": ":(",
  "": ":p"
};
const emojiPattern = new RegExp(`(${Object.keys(emojiMapper).join('|')})`, 'g');

const lookup = (emoji) => (found => found ? ' ' + found : emoji)(emojiMapper[emoji]);

const onPaste = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  transformTextWithEmoji(text, e.target);
};

// Based on: https://gist.github.com/paradite/f66862dbfb61001c8dd09680747eec06
const transformTextWithEmoji = (text, target) => {
  const cursorPosStart = target.selectionStart;
  const cursorPosEnd = target.selectionEnd;
  const textBefore = target.value.substring(0, cursorPosStart);
  const textAfter = target.value.substring(cursorPosEnd);
  const transformed = replaceAllEmoji(text);
  target.value = textBefore + transformed + textAfter;
  setTimeout(() => {
    const anchorOffset = cursorPosStart + transformed.length;
    target.selectionStart = target.selectionEnd = anchorOffset;
  });
};

const replaceAllEmoji = (text) =>
  text.replace(emojiPattern, (_, emoji) => lookup(emoji));

document.querySelector('#my-field').addEventListener('paste', onPaste);
```

```html
<textarea id="my-field" rows="2" cols="60">Hello World!</textarea>

<!-- 1. Copy: "It works! " -->
<!-- 2. Paste in <textarea>     -->
<!-- 3. ???                     -->
<!-- 4. Profit                  -->
```

Here is a more complete example. It includes more emoji, and uses a reducer instead of a regular expression.

I borrowed the key-value pairs from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581503/1762224).

```js
// Decide which key-value pair to keep... 
const emojiLookup = {
  "": "o/",
  "": "</3",
  "": "<3",
  "": "8-D",
  "": "8D",
  "": ":-D",
  "": "=-3",
  "": "=-D",
  "": "=3",
  "": "=D",
  "": "B^D",
  "": "X-D",
  "": "XD",
  "": "x-D",
  "": "xD",
  "": ":')",
  "": ":'-)",
  "": ":-))",
  "": "8)",
  "": ":)",
  "": ":-)",
  "": ":3",
  "": ":D",
  "": ":]",
  "": ":^)",
  "": ":c)",
  "": ":o)",
  "": ":}",
  "": ":っ)",
  "": "=)",
  "": "=]",
  "": "0:)",
  "": "0:-)",
  "": "0:-3",
  "": "0:3",
  "": "0;^)",
  "": "O:-)",
  "": "3:)",
  "": "3:-)",
  "": "}:)",
  "": "}:-)",
  "": "*)",
  "": "*-)",
  "": ":-,",
  "": ";)",
  "": ";-)",
  "": ";-]",
  "": ";D",
  "": ";]",
  "": ";^)",
  "": ":-|",
  "": ":|",
  "": ":(",
  "": ":-(",
  "": ":-<",
  "": ":-[",
  "": ":-c",
  "": ":<",
  "": ":[",
  "": ":c",
  "": ":{",
  "": ":っC",
  "": "%)",
  "": "%-)",
  "": ":-P",
  "": ":-b",
  "": ":-p",
  "": ":-Þ",
  "": ":-þ",
  "": ":P",
  "": ":b",
  "": ":p",
  "": ":Þ",
  "": ":þ",
  "": ";(",
  "": "=p",
  "": "X-P",
  "": "XP",
  "": "d:",
  "": "x-p",
  "": "xp",
  "": ":-||",
  "": ":@",
  "": ":-.",
  "": ":-/",
  "": ":/",
  "": ":L",
  "": ":S",
  "": ":\\",
  "": "=/",
  "": "=L",
  "": "=\\",
  "": ":'(",
  "": ":'-(",
  "": "^5",
  "": "^<_<",
  "": "o/\\o",
  "": "|-O",
  "": "|;-)",
  "": ":###..",
  "": ":-###..",
  "": "D-':",
  "": "D8",
  "": "D:",
  "": "D:<",
  "": "D;",
  "": "D=",
  "": "DX",
  "": "v.v",
  "": "8-0",
  "": ":-O",
  "": ":-o",
  "": ":O",
  "": ":o",
  "": "O-O",
  "": "O_O",
  "": "O_o",
  "": "o-o",
  "": "o_O",
  "": "o_o",
  "": ":$",
  "": "#-)",
  "": ":#",
  "": ":&",
  "": ":-#",
  "": ":-&",
  "": ":-X",
  "": ":X",
  "": ":-J",
  "": ":*",
  "": ":^*",
  "": "ಠ_ಠ",
  "": "*\\0/*",
  "": "\\o/",
  "": ":>",
  "": ">.<",
  "": ">:(",
  "": ">:)",
  "": ">:-)",
  "": ">:/",
  "": ">:O",
  "": ">:P",
  "": ">:[",
  "": ">:\\",
  "": ">;)",
  "": ">_>^",
};

const onPaste = (e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  const text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
  transformTextWithEmoji(text, e.target);
};

// Based on: https://gist.github.com/paradite/f66862dbfb61001c8dd09680747eec06
const transformTextWithEmoji = (text, target) => {
  const cursorPosStart = target.selectionStart;
  const cursorPosEnd = target.selectionEnd;
  const textBefore = target.value.substring(0, cursorPosStart);
  const textAfter = target.value.substring(cursorPosEnd);
  const transformed =  replaceAllEmoji(text);
  target.value = textBefore + transformed + textAfter;
  setTimeout(() => {
    const anchorOffset = cursorPosStart + transformed.length;
    target.selectionStart = target.selectionEnd = anchorOffset;
  });
};

const replaceAllEmoji = (text) =>
  Object.entries(emojiLookup).reduce((result, [emoji, ascii]) =>
    result.replace(emoji, ' ' + ascii), text);

document.querySelector('#my-field').addEventListener('paste', onPaste);
```

```html
<textarea id="my-field" rows="2" cols="60">Hello World!</textarea>

<!-- 1. Copy: "It works! " -->
<!-- 2. Paste in <textarea>     -->
<!-- 3. ???                     -->
<!-- 4. Profit                  -->
```